# Crystal Reports 2008: Convert past date to future date

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Crystal version: Crystal Reports 2008

I have a report that I need to reference a past date (9/18/2011) and have any items with that date be "converted" to a future date (10/02/2011).  One of my report sections is a group by this date.  NOTE: I can't change the date on the DB.

Any ideas?

```
Currently:
Date:       Project:
9/18/2011   Project1
9/18/2011   Project4
9/18/2011   Project5
9/30/2011   Project2
10/2/2011   Project3

Convert the dates to look like this on the report:
Date:       Project:
9/30/2011   Project2
10/2/2011   Project1
10/2/2011   Project3
10/2/2011   Project4
10/2/2011   Project5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new formula to group-by/display instead:

```
if {Table.TheDate} = date(2011,09,18) then date(2011,10,02)
    else {Table.TheDate}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//{@date_field}
//replace table.date_field with correct value
IIf({table.date_field} = Date(2011,09,18), Date(2011,10,02), {table.date_field})
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using IIF in this case?

Comment: No benefit, I prefer its brevity.